# How can I alter the default time interval for appointment start/End in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I wish to set to be able to select time intervals in 5 mins intervals for start and end times for an appointment in Outlook 2007 rather than the current default of 30 mins.

So the dropdown box will display 00-05-10-15 etc rather than existing 00-30-00

Can you please help me. Thanks.MM